# EXTRACTVALUE from Oracle CLOB-XML returning NULL

Tags: xml, oracle

Can somebody explain, how to extract "NamedSubString Name" and "Value" into a table of two columns?
My XML data is in a CLOB column.
I started with the following code, but it returns always NULL.

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(clob_column), '/XMLScript/Command/Print/text()') 
FROM table;
```

```
<XMLScript Version="2.0">
    <Command> 
        <Print JobName="2381_4750_20210330_104608">
            <Format>\\molpesr03\data\molpe\d\projs\Celldok\entw\Vorlagen\Bartender.txt</Format>

            <NamedSubString Name="WF_PRODUKTART">
                <Value>ÖÄÜöäüß'</Value> 
            </NamedSubString> 

            <NamedSubString Name="FORMAT"><Value></Value></NamedSubString><NamedSubString Name="IDENTICALCOPIESOFLABEL"><Value></Value></NamedSubString><NamedSubString Name="JOBNAME"><Value></Value></NamedSubString><NamedSubString Name="NAMEDSUBSTRINGS"><Value></Value></NamedSubString><NamedSubString Name="PRINTER"><Value></Value></NamedSubString><NamedSubString Name="PRINTTOFILENAME"><Value></Value></NamedSubString><NamedSubString Name="WF_AUFPOS_ID"><Value>16487298</Value></NamedSubString>

            <PrintSetup> 
                <IdenticalCopiesOfLabel>1</IdenticalCopiesOfLabel>
                <Printer>Zebra ZT410 (300 dpi)</Printer>
                <PrintToFileName></PrintToFileName> 
            </PrintSetup> 
        </Print> 
    </Command> 
</XMLScript>
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extract the values using multiple `CROSS JOIN`s and the `XMLTABLE` function like this:

```sql
WITH
    your_table
    AS
        (SELECT    EMPTY_CLOB ()
                || '<XMLScript Version="2.0">
    <Command> 
        <Print JobName="2381_4750_20210330_104608">
            <Format>\\molpesr03\data\molpe\d\projs\Celldok\entw\Vorlagen\Bartender.txt</Format>
            <NamedSubString Name="WF_PRODUKTART">
                <Value>ÖÄÜöäüß</Value> 
            </NamedSubString> 
            <NamedSubString Name="FORMAT"><Value></Value></NamedSubString><NamedSubString Name="IDENTICALCOPIESOFLABEL"><Value></Value></NamedSubString><NamedSubString Name="JOBNAME"><Value></Value></NamedSubString><NamedSubString Name="NAMEDSUBSTRINGS"><Value></Value></NamedSubString><NamedSubString Name="PRINTER"><Value></Value></NamedSubString><NamedSubString Name="PRINTTOFILENAME"><Value></Value></NamedSubString><NamedSubString Name="WF_AUFPOS_ID"><Value>16487298</Value></NamedSubString>
            <PrintSetup> 
                <IdenticalCopiesOfLabel>1</IdenticalCopiesOfLabel>
                <Printer>Zebra ZT410 (300 dpi)</Printer>
                <PrintToFileName></PrintToFileName> 
            </PrintSetup> 
        </Print> 
    </Command> 
</XMLScript>'    AS clob_column
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT d.*
  FROM your_table  yt
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE ('/XMLScript/Command/Print'
                 PASSING xmltype (yt.clob_column)
                 COLUMNS records XMLTYPE PATH 'NamedSubString') r
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE ('NamedSubString'
                 PASSING r.records
                 COLUMNS "NAME" PATH '@Name', "VALUE" PATH 'Value') d;
```

```
                     NAME       VALUE
_________________________ ___________
WF_PRODUKTART             ╓─▄÷Σⁿ▀
FORMAT
IDENTICALCOPIESOFLABEL
JOBNAME
NAMEDSUBSTRINGS
PRINTER
PRINTTOFILENAME
WF_AUFPOS_ID              16487298
```

Comment: Thx. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: If this answer solved your question, please mark the question as answered so others do not take time with additional answers when your question has already been answered.